# External secret is not working on kubernetes

Tags: azure-devops, kubernetes-secrets, external-secrets-operator, external-secrets

I have implemented external secrets to detch values from azure key vault in kubernetes cluster. I worked fine for two environments but in third environment it is not working. It created secret store and validates it but the external secret doesn't provide any status and creates no secrets. Here is the screenshot os external secret resource in kubernetes:
[image]

I have tested the configurations and found that everything is configured perfectly but still unable to create the secrets using external secrets

Comment: hi. could you find why the status is not being updated?

Answer (score 0):

After syncing your changes into the cluster, try deleting the pod and wait for kubernetes to recreate the pod and check again if the secret are being exposed.

I faced the same problem while trying to use argocd to sync the changes but what I realised is that although most of the changes are deployed into the cluster, external secrets won't and manually restarting the pod fetches the updated secrets.